# Escaping hyphens (--) with printf in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following line:

```
printf "---- %.55s\n" "$1 --------------"
```

When I run this under bash I get the following error:

> printf: --: invalid option printf: usage: printf [-v var] format
>   [arguments]

This is because (I think) printf interprets the string "----" as the beginning of an argument. I have tried to escape this using "\" like so:

```
printf "\---- %.55s\n" "$1 --------------"
```

The following is the result:

> `\---- content of $1 -------`

As you can see the "\" became part of the output which is not what I want.

So the question is, **how can i persuade printf that I am not trying to pass a long argument**?

Comment: I found out shortly after that just putting a double hyphen "--"  before the actual string worked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To avoid an argument starting in `-` being interpreted as an option, you have a few different alternatives:

1) Move the minus signs form the format string to the argument string, possibly reflecting the new length of the printed string in the `%.s` format specifier. As in:

```
$ printf "%.60s\n" "---- $1 --------------"
```

2) `bash`'s builtin commands accept `--` as an option that instructs them to stop processing options and consider everything that follows as file-names and arguments. As in:

```
$ printf -- "---- %.55s\n" "$1 --------------"
```

3) You can substitute the minus signs with their octal codes. Actually, replacing just the first one works, as in:

```
$ printf "\055--- %.55s\n" "$1 --------------"
```